# Do I need to specify the pathname of a command added in `/etc/sudoers`, every time I run it with `sudo`?

Tags: sudo

For a line that I added to `/etc/sudoers`, for example:

```
t  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript
```

`/path/to` is in `PATH` of the current user `t`, but not in `PATH` of `root`.

```
$ sudo /path/to/myscript
```

works without password, but do I need to specify the pathname of the script every time I run the script with `sudo`?

```
$ sudo myscript
[sudo] password for t: 
sudo: changeCpuFreq.sh: command not found
```

doesn't work even with password, because  `myscript`'s path isn't in `PATH` of `root`.

```
$ sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" myscript
[sudo] password for t:
```

works with password, because `PATH` of `t` is copied to that of `root`, but the problem is that it still needs password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need per se to define the full pathname in sudoers; however you *should* do it for security reasons.

Otherwise, it is fairly easy to gain root privileges; you just need to invoke *another* binary with the same name, and *presto*, instant root privileges.

Comment: Thanks. How do you achieve "not need per se to define the full pathname" in `/etc/sudoers`? My post is whether I need to specify pathname when running it with `sudo`.

Comment: You do not use the full pathname, and configure a restricted `Defaults    secure_path`; nonetheless defining the full path gives you an extra layer of security.

Comment: Do I need to specify pathname to the command, when I run it with sudo?

Comment: If the pathname is there as in your first example, you need to do it, unless you create an alias. See this for other security considerations: http://www.openwall.com/lists/owl-users/2004/10/20/6

Comment: do you mean if pathname exists in `/etc/sudoers`, then it must also be specified when running the command? How do you "not use the full pathname, and configure a restricted Defaults secure_path"?

Comment: You use only for example, `t  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: xxxx` without any path and put in secure_path only `/bin`
 and `/usr/bin` (or add `/opt/bin` for instance).  I am going off, might improve both answers tomorrow a bit, 2AM here  in my timezone already.

Comment: I was wondering if you are available to add more details? Thanks.

Comment: Later on, busy with something else

Answer (score 0):

You can customize *sudo*'s search path for specific sudoers (or target users, commands, hosts, etc.) by editing either `/etc/sudoers` or one of `/etc/sudoers.d/*`.

**CAUTION!!!** If your *root* account is disabled, the use of *visudo* is **strongly** advised when editing *sudo*'s configuration.

The following defines a different search path for sudoer *myuser*:

```
Defaults:myuser secure_path="/path/to:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

The following defines a different search path when sudoing as *root*

```
Defaults>root secure_path="/path/to:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

The following defines a different search path only when calling `/path/to/myscript` through *sudo*:

```
Defaults!/path/to/myscript secure_path="/path/to:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Any of the above will integrate nicely with your "NOPASSWD" rule, and no path prefix will be needed when calling `sudo myscript`.

Comment: Oh, shoots... hadn't realized it was an old question. Oh, well... someone else may need this information